# Can I give a bounty to a commenter?

Tags: support, comments, bounty

I asked [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228398/why-does-my-desktop-file-execute-via-double-click-but-not-from-the-menu) a few days ago.  I got a couple of answers but nothing that worked so I added a bounty to try and get some more attention.

After placing the bounty, a user [commented](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228398/why-does-my-desktop-file-execute-via-double-click-but-not-from-the-menu#comment283251_229109) on one of the [original incorrect answers](https://askubuntu.com/a/229109/25082) and pointed out how with a syntax adjustment, it will work.  After successfully testing his suggestion I edited the incorrect answer to reflect the comment's correction so people having a similar problem would have an easier time finding the solution.

**I'd like to award the bounty to the commenter,** since he was the one who provided the working solution.  ***Other than suggesting he post the solution as an answer***, is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're feeling generous, you can just see if that user has any  answers worthy of a bonus (check their profile) then leave a bounty for one with an explanation.

Comment: Now ***that*** is a good idea.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No, You can't

You can't give bounty to the system because comments are less important and it may be removed without any warning. You can award bounty if he posted it as separate answer. But since it is already answered by editing current answer there is no need duplicating it